# Quickly find first entry with a value below or equal

Tags: python

Let's say in Python I have a list of files with their respective sizes, represented as a dict (I don't care about the structure, you can propose another one):

```
from random import randint

def gen_rand_fileslist(nbfiles=100, maxvalue=100):
    fileslist = {}
    for i in xrange(nbfiles):
        fileslist["file_"+str(i)] = randint(1, maxvalue)
    return fileslist

fileslist = gen_rand_fileslist(10)
```

Example `fileslist`:

```
{'file_0': 2,
 'file_1': 21,
 'file_2': 20,
 'file_3': 16,
 'file_4': 12,
 'file_5': 67,
 'file_6': 95,
 'file_7': 16,
 'file_8': 2,
 'file_9': 5}
```

Now I want to quickly find the highest value below the specified threshold. For example:

```
get_value_below(fileslist, threshold=25) # result should be 'file_1' with value 21
```

The function get_value_below() is to be called in a tight loop, so it should be as fast as possible, and any threshold can be specified (so sorting doesn't help directly).

Is there a way to be faster than just walking through the whole list (linear time)?

Comment: Only way it will be faster than linear is if the list is sorted

Comment: In my implementation, the list is sorted, but the problem remains that I need in a tight loop to get a random value that is less or equal to a threshold. Having the list sorted doesn't help directly (except when using a binary/dichotomic search such as in the bisect module, as indicated by JuniorCompressor's answer).

Comment: It makes the search log(n) vs O(n) so a major improvement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It all depends on how often you are going to search for a threshold in the `fileslist`. If you are going to do more than `Θ(log n)` queries, then it's better to sort first and then perform a binary search for each query. Otherwise, if you want to perform one query only, then yes it's better to linear search since the element you want can be virtually anywhere and you'll definitely need to visit each element of the list.

If you are planning to use the sorting first and binary searching then, then use [bisect_right](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html#bisect.bisect_right) which for an input `x`, it will return the position in the list that contains the biggest element lower or equal to `x`.

Comment: This is spot on, so I accept your answer. Technically, this is a binary/dichotomic search, I don't know how I didn't think about it before, but in fact I'm glad because I discovered about the bisect module thank's to your answer. In addition, the doc give an example of a function find_le() which is exactly what I need. In addition, the [bisect.insort() (insertion sort algorithm)](http://pymotw.com/2/bisect/) will also be of great help.

Answer (score 2):

I propose pandas DataFrame, which solves your searching problem fast.

Consider the following example:

```
from pandas import DataFrame as df

th = 25

d = df(['file_0', 'file_1', 'file_2', 
         'file_3', 'file_4', 'file_5', 
         'file_6', 'file_7', 'file_8', 
         'file_9'],
         [2,21,20,16,12,67,95,16,2,5])

x = d.loc[d.index < th]
x = x.loc[x.index == max(x.index)]
print x
```

**OUT:**

```
         0
21  file_1
```

Don't search linearly through a sorted array, use binary search (duh). On the one hand, this is CS 101 kid's stuff. On the other, I didn't know about the bisect library and had code littered with `np.nonzero(sorted<=x)[0]`. Once I switched to using bisect_left/bisect_right I saw a huge performance improvement. Edit: In the comments, Peter pointed out that NumPy implements a faster binary search called searchsorted; you (and I) should probably use that instead!.

Some useful citations from http://blog.explainmydata.com/2012/07/expensive-lessons-in-python-performance.html:

> Wes McKinney is a genius. If you're implementing anything Wes McKinney has already put in his library pandas, just stop. His code is faster, more robust, and more likely to be correct than anything you're about to write. Want rolling window aggregators? Use pandas.
>
> Need to handle missing data? Use pandas. Are you writing some sort of unbelievably ugly hack which attempts to implement joins and group-by's over NumPy arrays but actually manages to spend 3 hours computing a subtly incorrect result? (I have done this). Jesus Christ, just stop and use pandas.

Comment: Thank you very much, indeed I thought about pandas that I extensively used, but in my case I need to rely on no external library except native (sorry that I didn't mention it in my question). However, your link is very interesting, and I didn't know about Numpy's searchsorted nor that namedtuples were huge memory savers. So I'll give you a bounty for that!